# Why does a class library does not have projecttypeguids tag in its .*proj file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Recently I cam across these  element in the .*proj files of a .net solution. Each guid represents a type of project but I could not see any "projecttypeguid" tag. Why is this so?

Comment: Not sure about the reasoning, but I can confirm that class libraries seem to omit the projecttypeguid field.